# simple html dom to exclude paragraph with class

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I have this code and i want first paragraph as output I tried to filter with paragraph but I am getting second paragraph

I am only interested in first paragraph text.

```
   <div class="bq_fq_lrg" style="margin:0px">
     <p>this text i want.</p>
     <p class="bq_fq_a">
       <a href="xz.html">this text i dont want.</a>
     </p>
   </div>
```

I tried this but it is giving second paragraph

```
  foreach($html->find('div.bq_fq_lrg p[0]') as $e)
```

The `$html` variable is an instance of [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

I am getting the content of the paragraph like this:

```
 $op1 = $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `!` in attributes to get that particular value. Consider this example:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html_string = '<div class="bq_fq_lrg" style="margin:0px">
     <p>this text i want.</p>
     <p class="bq_fq_a">
       <a href="xz.html">this text i dont want.</a>
     </p>
   </div>';
$html = str_get_html($html_string);
foreach($html->find('div.bq_fq_lrg p[!class]') as $value) {
    echo $value->innertext; // this text i want.
}
```